# django update form has no attribute save

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to create a form which will allow users to update their name, I am using a forms.form instead of ModelForm because it gives you more control over the styling of the form because you can use widgets. when I go to save the form it says that updateNameForm has no attribute save

view

```
def UpdateName(request,user_id):


if request.method == "POST":

   form = UpdateNameForm(request.POST,initial=initial)
   if form.is_valid():
     name = form.cleaned_data['name']
     form.save()
else:
    form = UpdateNameForm(initial=initial)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateNameForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label="*Status",
        widget=forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'class' : 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'})
    )
```

Comment: share your forms.py

Answer (score 3):

A standard form class indeed has no `save` attribute - it doesn't know anything about any models to save to. You need to use a ModelForm.

Note also you need to pass the `instance` argument to the form to make it update an existing instance, rather than create a new one. You probably don't need `initial` at all.

Comment: is there a way you can save the form using forms.Form instead of ModelForm

Comment: Not without writing tons of code. Why would you want to? Why don't you want to use a ModelForm? This is literally *exactly* what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

```
def UpdateName(request,user_id):
user = get_user(user_id)

if request.method == "POST":

   form = UpdateNameForm(request.POST,initial=initial)
   if form.is_valid():
     name = form.cleaned_data['name']
     user.name = name
     user.save()
else:
    form = UpdateNameForm(initial=initial)
```